# Query on splitting and regex

Tags: python-3.x, regex, string, list, split

I have a string that has a name and two phone numbers that are split,

```
a = '19654 12876 70103 50919 Anish Krishnan'
```

first I am joining the numbers using re

```
re.sub(r'(\d)\s+(\d)', r'\1\2', a)
```

Doing that, I get

```
'19654128767010350919 Anish Krishnan'
```

Now, i need to split the number alone at the 10th digit so that i get two full phone numbers

This is the output i need

```
'1965412876 7010350919 Anish Krishnan'
```

Can someone tell me how to do it, Thanks.

Comment: if the format is always 4 groups of numbers? why are you joining them first? couldn't you just specify an expression which matches all 4 groups and joins together the first 2 and the last 2 but with a space between?

Comment: It can be n number of groups. I tried that , but if there is a 3rd group i didn't work.

Comment: n number of groups of 5? so if there are 15 total digits (3 groups) what do you expect the output to be?

Comment: Group of 5, but the number of groups are always even.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just substitute repetition of 5 digits, followed by a space followed by another 5 digits it will match both pairs of digits and join them:

```
>>> re.sub(r"(\d{5})\s(\d{5})", r"\1\2", "19654 12876 70103 50919 Anish Krishnan")
'1965412876 7010350919 Anish Krishnan'
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to consume all the digits next to each other using `\d+`:

```
import re

output = re.sub("(\d+)\s+(\d+)", r"\1\2", string)
print(output)  # 1965412876 7010350919 Anish Krishnan
```